# Is there any alternative to Java's JNA library for C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke, jna

**JNA** has a great collection of native functions, constants and structures. I need a similar library for C#. But I can not find anything after a lot of searching. Does anybody know any alternative for JNA library in C#?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, rather, which WinAPI are you trying to call in your Java code that can't be exposed through "normal" Java libraries? C# is a language that (typically) "links" against the .NET library; if there's a specific .NET function you need, you might check out `jni4net` (http://jni4net.com/) .. otherwise you'll probably have to COM/PInvoke/IPC if the Java API's don't have what you need.

Comment: I am not asking it for any specific task/project. I need it to use it later in other projects in future. A library like JNA would help me greatly and reduce my workhour.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a direct equivalent of JNA for C#. However, by using [P\Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) you can call any (or almost any) native function. Another aproach migh be to use [COM Interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645712%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Here is a general [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173184.aspx) about interoperability in C#.

As you said using P\Invoke might be troublesome. But, there is [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/) web site which might be very helpful. It contains declarations of many native funcions, structures... ready to use.

Comment: Yeah. I know that. But its a lot of pain to find values for constants and writing functions in every project.

Comment: [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/) is indeed a great site. But I hope there is somebody who collected all of them and united them together.